# How To Change The Header Background Color On Wordpress Website

Tags: css, wordpress, header, background-color

I'm trying to change the entire header background color of my wordpress website by using the "additional css", what would I need to enter in to achieve this? I'd like the entire header to be black.

I've tried various things but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Can you provide your site url ?

Comment: Sure, https://pixrepair.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the css for black header

```
.main-header-bar {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

In addition, you also may like this, White logo >>

```
.site-title a, .site-title a:focus, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:visited {
    color: #f3f4f5;
}
```

White Menu color >>

```
.main-header-menu a, .ast-header-custom-item a {
    color: #f3f4f5;
}
```